# Disable windows 7 auto-restart after end-tasking certain processes

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

So I was end tasking a bunch of processes and I miss-clicked and hit some windows process (`lsm.exe` I believe, but that's not the point) that gave me the usual "windows will now shut down in one minute" nonsense. So I casually ran `shutdown -a`, but this time producing `1115 A system shutdown is in progress` and the message didn't disappear and I was forced to wait for a reboot. Finally I'm here asking, **how can I abort such a shutdown or disable it from happening at all?**

Note: I'm not advocating this, I'm sure there's *a* reason behind the shutdown. To emphasize the why I'm asking this,

- Why shutdown in the first place / what *is* the reason?
- Why doesn't windows just restart the process instead?
- If it's really that important, why isn't it part of the kernel and why allow a user space app (i.e. task manager) to kill it?
- If it's really that important, why is it safe to allow me to keep using windows while the timer ticks down and not just indefinitely?
- Why not halt/blue screen instead of waiting dangerously for the timer?

I'm strongly of the opinion I should have the power to break things, and if I do it's my own fault. To respond to a comment from [a related post](https://superuser.com/questions/729618/killing-wininit-exe-shuts-down-windows): *"It is analogous to asking Hey, why does my system turn off when I yank out the power cord?"*, I'm asking because there is no sudden death and my observations are windows is just making life difficult, doing something illogical and treating me like a child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be possible to remove the *critical* flag from a process before killing it, as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/344488/Process-Kill) under *System Critical (undocumented)*, calling `NtSetInformationProcess`. However this doesn't solve the problem of forcibly aborting an existing shutdown.

[This link](https://4sysops.com/archives/four-ways-to-stop-a-shutdown-or-reboot/) contains some alternatives, reiterated below:

1. Change the system clock to confuse the timer
2. `shutdown -a`, but as already said this doesn't work
3. Activate the *Shutdown Event Tracker* (run `gpedit.msc`, `Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Display Shutdown Event Tracker`)
4. Some app called [`shutdown guard`](https://code.google.com/p/shutdownguard/downloads/list).

Answer (score 0):

There are certain processes that are vital to the Windows Security subsystem.  If those processes ever die, the system is supposed to reboot to make sure they're started again.

Processes like crss, lsass, svchost, smss, and wininit should never be killed.  It was probably wininit that did it.

Comment: @AndréDaniel ooh. not quite a restart, killing `kdeinit4` just kills login. again I find it bizarre that everything still works until I hit "ok". can you say why?

Comment: @jozxyqk I didn't mean the KDE init, I mean the [real init](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init). It should cause an instant kernel panic if you manage to kill it (requires root privileges obviously).

Comment: @AndréDaniel now instant kernel panic I can relate to. something failed. halt/crash. My issue is with this *something really bad happened so lets wait around for a little bit and then restart*.